# What unforeseen consequences would arise from poor and rich employee taxes?

Tags: taxation

A poor-employee$^1$fee is a tax on businesses who pay their employees and contractors below some pre-determined, annually adjusted, hourly rate hereafter called the target minimum wage. At implementation, it is a small percentage (5 or 10) of the gap between the employee's cash hourly rate and the target rate and slowly grows over roughly two decades to 80%. Employers paying staff on commission will pay a similar fee based on the equivalent wage assuming twelve hour days.

Expected consequences:

- Fewer wage earners working at poverty wages
- Fewer business models relying on cheap labor (perhaps offset by models relying on skilled labor)
- A reduction in non-cash perks (health insurance, etc...) below target wage rate
- Higher government revenue
- Drastically reduce poverty-wage earners
- Increase unemployment (but by how much?!?)
- Decrease in government expenditures for poverty related services

A rich-employee$^2$fee is a tax on business who pay employees beyond some pre-determined, inflation-adjusted rate of total annual compensation, hereafter called the target maximum compensation (TMC). The tax rate is 100% for all compensation above the target maximum rate, so if the company pays TMC + Extra, they also owe Extra for the rich-employee fee. The TMC can grow by as much as quadruple based on the percentage of worker and contractor hours remunerated above the TMW, i.e. TMC$_0(1 + 3h)$.

Expected Consequences:

- Companies will scour the new law for loopholes that allow them to continue doing business in country while paying taxes elsewhere
- Drastic increase in government revenue, but only until the loopholes are found or CEO compensation goes down
- CEOs will have more work to justify their compensation
- Companies will suddenly have more money for employees
- New legislative candidates will have a much easier time raising money [to repeal the law]

Both of these taxes are fees and unrelated to the business' profitability. For reference, I expect TMW to be roughly $\\\$40/$hour and TMC$_0$ to be a half million per year for a US implementation. What am I missing?

$^1\,^2\,_{\text{If these taxes already exist under other [almost certainly better] names, please indicate}}$